# Why is the object I try to retrieve from the localstorage null and after reload it is defined?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am using NGX-Webstorage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage.

I have a login function in my `auth.service`

```
login(username, hashedPassword){
    return this.http.get(this.api + 'login', {params: {username: username, password: hashedPassword}})
    .subscribe(user => {
      if(user){
       this.initilizeApp(user);
       this.router.navigate(['/assignments'])
      } else {...}
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

There are constants in my app which I try to store in the localstorage in the function `initilizeApp()` which is working

```
initilizeApp(user){
    forkJoin({data1: getData1(user.ID), data2: getData2()}).subscribe(val => {
       val.user = {};
       val.user = user;
       this.localStorage.store('init', val)
    }) // has user object
}
```

The problem is, after the intitialization part in the login function, I navigate to `assignments` and in `ngOnInit` I try to retrieve the user from the localstorage:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.user = this.localStorage.retrieve("init").user;
}
```

but `user` is undefined and after reload `user` is defined. Since `store`and `retrieve` are sync functions, I don't know why the object isnt in the localstorage when I try to retrieve it directly after storage..

Comment: please add the code of `this.observables`.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon One moment

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I tried to reduce the code such that is easier to read. But now I think everything should be clear I hope. The function ```initializeApp(user)``` is working fine since the correct object is logged in the console.

Comment: if the getData function relies on asynchronous tasks (like an http request) it might explains the value is not setted when you navigate for the first time.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon But what can I do about it? It is as you said, the two functions are http requests to fetch some data from the database. How can I await the whole forkJoin function before returning to the login function again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After retrieving the user from the http request, you change your observable to return the value of the new forkjoin observable.
This way the navigation will only happens when the localStorage value is saved.

```
login(username, hashedPassword){
    return this.http.get(this.api + 'login', {params: {username: username, password: hashedPassword}})
    .pipe(
      filter(user => !!user)
      switchMap(user => {
        return forkjoin({data1: getData1(user.ID), data2: getData2()})
      })
    )
    .subscribe(user => {
       // you shouldn't need to nest the user into a 'val' object
       this.localStorage.store('init', user)
       this.router.navigate(['/assignments'])
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Except if there is a special need to nest the user into a 'val' object, you can retrieve it this way.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.user = this.localStorage.retrieve("init");
}
```